# Insert NSArray into an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

If I have a NSArray, can I put this into a NSDictionary?
If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` can use *any* objects as values, and any objects that conforms to `NSCopying`as keys. So in your case:

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c"];

NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];

NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[mutableDict setObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];
```

Comment: NSDictionary cannot use just any objects as keys.  They have to conform to `NSCopying`.

Comment: @JeremyP: yes indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with `myArray`:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

If you want a mutable dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[myMutableDictionary setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

If you just want a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read this:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i